# why are my new flurry parameters not showing up?

Tags: ios, flurry

I have been tracking flurry events in my iOS app and they show up in the dashboard. I tried to add a new parameter to an existing event, and then activated the event on my phone a bunch of times yesterday, but I still don't see any occurrences of the new parameters on that event in the dashboard.

Does flurry not allow you to add new parameters to an existing event?

Answer (score 2):

We noticed this too a little bit ago, and emailed support@flurry.com about it. Here's what they said:

> Typically, Flurry sessions never completely report back to Flurry until the next time the app is launched. So, be sure to launch the app one more time after you complete a testing session. Furthermore you should make sure you launch the same build of the app. If you make a new build between sessions you may be removing incomplete sessions before they get reported. If you are running tests via an emulator, please ensure that the home button is pressed before closing the app. Then you should relaunch the app one more time with the same build to ensure all session data is reported.
>
> If the app pauses or moves to the background for more than 10 seconds, the NEXT time the app runs, Flurry agent will automatically create a new session and end the previous session. Otherwise, Flurry agent will continue the same session. This can be updated via the setSessionContinueSeconds method. If the app is terminated, a new session will be created when the app runs again.
>
> When we receive the complete session data (after the app is relaunched) the event logs should update first within 10 minutes or so. Please allow about 6 hours for this to populate to the dashboard, parameters pie chart etc.

Basically, what we were doing is just booting up the app, doing the thing that would send an analytic event, then quitting the app or whatever. Which wasn't giving the flurry agent enough time to actually send the event. (turns out that, contrary to the log events, flurry wasn't sending the log event right then :/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Flurry SDK only communicates with our servers twice per session. The first time is when the session is started and sets the timestamp for the session, counts a new user or updates an existing user as active. The second time is when the session ends and all event data is sent in one batch.

In cases where we do not receive the second report we refer to this as an "incomplete session". This arises in a few scenarios but mainly

-No network connection when the session ends
-The app is sent to the background for >10 seconds and the session continues running

In these cases the event data is stored on the device's disk and sent the next time the app is launched.